# WebService to return data in a certain format

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am trying to replicate a webservice provided by a company which I am trying to use for my testing environment.

The original webservice returns the data like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDoAccountMasters xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <doAccountMasters>
    <MasterNum>int</MasterNum>
    <MasterName>string</MasterName>
    <ErrorCode>int</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDescription>string</ErrorDescription>
  </doAccountMasters>
  <doAccountMasters>
    <MasterNum>int</MasterNum>
    <MasterName>string</MasterName>
    <ErrorCode>int</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDescription>string</ErrorDescription>
  </doAccountMasters>
</ArrayOfDoAccountMasters>
```

At the moment I have the following function:

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Returns Array 5 IDs < x", EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function GetCustomerIDs(ID As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim output As New List(Of String)()
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand( _
     "select top 5 p.MasterNum, p.MasterName, p.ErrorCode, p.ErrorDescription from person.person p where BusinessEntityID<" & ID, connection)

    connection.Open()
    Dim dr = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read
        output.Add(dr.Item(0))
    End While

    connection.Close()
    Return output

End Function
```

which returns the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>string</string>
  <string>string</string>
  <string>string</string>
  <string>string</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Apparently, my method doesn't return the data in the same format. How can I modify the code to make it look the same as their method? How do I need to format my return data?

Comment: Original service returns array of `doAccountMasters` class.

Comment: @L.B How about the formatting of the string elements?

Comment: @nectarines: How are you getting your data? I mean from which source you are getting data that you will return

Comment: Create a `doAccountMasters` class, and then return a `List(Of doAccountMasters)`, rather than a `List(Of String)`.  Also, .ASMX is a legacy technology - you should be using WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is returning exactly what you told it to - a List of Strings.  The service you're attempting to imitate is returning a List of doAccountMasters.  Your method needs to return a List of doAccountMasters to get an output like the original service.

I strongly recommend that you use WCF for this, as ASMX web services are legacy technology.  In WCF you could use a `DataContract` for the `doAccountMasters`, and then the normal service interface and class that implements the interface.  It would look something like this (There is more to WCF than just the below parts - you'll have to host the service in IIS or some other hosting solution):

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class doAccountMasters

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property MasterNum As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property MasterName As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ErrorCode As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ErrorDescription As String
EndClass
```

The Interface:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IMyService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetCustomerIDs(ID As String) As List(Of doAccountMasters)
End Interface
```

The Service Implementation:

```
Public Class MyService 
    Implements IMyService

    Public Function GetCustomerIDs(ID As String) As List(Of doAccountMasters)

        Dim output As New List(Of doAccountMasters)()

        Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand( _
            "select top 5 p.MasterNum, p.MasterName, p.ErrorCode, p.ErrorDescription from person.person p where BusinessEntityID<@ID", connection)

        connection.Open()
        sqlCommand.Paramters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, ID)
        Dim dr = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read
            Dim master As doAccountMasters = New doAccountMasters()
            master.MasterNum = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item(0))
            master.MasterName = dr.Item(1).ToString()
            master.ErrorCode = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item(2))
            master.ErrorDescription = dr.Item(3).ToString()
            output.Add(master)
        End While

        connection.Close()
        Return output
    End Function
End Class
```

If you must stick with .ASMX, you could use the same class (minus the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes) and the same logic:

```
Public Class doAccountMasters

    Public Property MasterNum As Integer
    Public Property MasterName As String
    Public Property ErrorCode As Integer
    Public Property ErrorDescription As String
End Class

<WebMethod(Description:="Returns Array 5 IDs < x", EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function GetCustomerIDs(ID As String) As List(Of doAccountMasters)

    Dim output As New List(Of doAccountMasters)()

    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand( _
        "select top 5 p.MasterNum, p.MasterName, p.ErrorCode, p.ErrorDescription from person.person p where BusinessEntityID<@ID", connection)

    connection.Open()
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, ID)
    Dim dr = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read
        Dim master As doAccountMasters = New doAccountMasters()
        master.MasterNum = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item(0))
        master.MasterName = dr.Item(1).ToString()
        master.ErrorCode = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item(2))
        master.ErrorDescription = dr.Item(3).ToString()
        output.Add(master)
    End While

    connection.Close()
    Return output

End Function
```

The above codes also utilize parameterized queries, and I'm making a guess that `ID` is an integer based on the SQL command you have.

Comment: I'm getting an error: Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of WebServiceTest1.doAccountMasters)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'. That is on the 'Return output' Any ideas?

Comment: @nectarines - If you were using the ASMX code snippet, I had an error in the code.  The function was still returning `List(Of String)` - I have changed it to `Public Function GetCustomerIDs(ID As String) As List(Of doAccountMasters)`.

Comment: Ok, that is the class doAccountMasters.vb. When I compile, how can I see the webservice description on the html page? What should I do to list the webservice method? Your answer is great by the way. I mean if I want to test the method, at the moment is not being displayed in the compiled TestService.asmx.vb

Comment: @nectarines - I haven't worked with legacy web services in a long time, but you should be able to browse to the web service page in your browser by going to the address of the service.  That page should list all the available methods - if it's not, it's probably a property setting in the `<WebMethod>` attribute.